# How to restore corrupted OnePlus 5 from with a red triangle warning?

Tags: reboot, system-error, oneplus-5

This happened after a system update to Android 9. The device is working properly but I'm getting "Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and may not work properly" with a red triangle warning every time I reboot. Formatting it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: That warning is due to `dm-verity` corruption: https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/boot-flow#dm-verity-corruption. Did you root your device, unlocked bootloader etc?

Comment: No, I didn't root my device. Just system update from OnePlus to Oxygen OS 9.0.0.

Comment: Then something went wrong during update. Which method did you use to update?

Comment: I just downgraded my phone to Oxygen OS 4.5.8 and the warning is gone. However, after the downgrade, I did an over the air upgrade from OnePlus to Oxygen OS 9.0.9 and then warning is back again. What does it mean?

Comment: Official updates come from OEM, so OP can tell better. Contact customer services.

Comment: @quarkytale Don't install that update. I believe something is broken in the update, which has created a security issue and SafetyNet check is failing. Try to contact the customer care, or wait patiently - sooner or later they will find the bug.

Comment: I'm facing that since more than a year, spoke to customer care twice, apparently they know about this issue and have a hack to booting the phone when the screen is stuck on that. A more permanent solution is a remote flash session from their support team but I never got a call/email back to schedule that  session.